# What are the white like spots just above the mango?

Tags: fruit-trees

[image]

Sometime earlier the mango, amla trees are stuck by a problem of the white fungus like things which stopped their fruit growing.
please give me the solution!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [Mealybug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mealybug) you can mix soap with water and spray them, and/or use neem oil.